# How do I remove an object from tiled?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Lets say I placed an object in an object layer in Tiled. How should I separate these objects from each other when writing the code? (example: we collided with the body of a coin and don't need the body anymore)

Answer (score 0):

For the tile layer just set cell to null.

```
   //Rectangle tmp = new Rectangle();
   if (colideTileLayer.getCell(ix, iy) != null) {
      tmp.set(ix * tileWidth, iy * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
      if (tmp.overlaps(rectangle)) {
        colideTileLayer.setCell(ix, iy, null); //THIS IS LINE
        GameManager.INSTANCE.incResult();
        result = true;
      }
    }
```

In case your obstacle is defined in the object layer and visually represented in tile layer recalculate which tiles need to be erased, based on object position.

Than remove an object from object layer, use remove method.

```
//MapObjects objects = layer.getObjects(); //you read if from object layer
//MapObject object = getColidedObject(); //you need to know what to remove 
objects.remove(object); //remove
```

Comment: Whenever i use the objects.remove(object) it doesn't seem to be removing the object, not sure why this happens. I'm not looking to remove a tile from a tilelayer but a whole object from a object layer.

Comment: Try if your object exists (before and after) in this layer (use getIndex method).  \n  /** Get the index of the object in the collection, or -1 if no such object exists. */
 public int getIndex (MapObject object) {
  return objects.indexOf(object, true);
 }